# Angular 5 consume json consisting of one object

Tags: json, angular, rest

I am working on a barcode scanning app with angular.
The number of the barcode returns a json containing a "box" object. How can i parse the box json to a box class in angular?

This is my existing code:

```
//Injectable Dataservice
export class BoxService {
//url vars
urlBegin:string = "url";
urlEinde:string = "/last-order";
url:string;
test;
constructor(@Inject(HttpClient) private http: HttpClient){
}

getBox(barcode):Observable<Box>{
    this.url = this.urlBegin + barcode + this.urlEinde;
    return this.http.get<Box>(this.url);
}
```

}

```
// My component using the service showBox() is the method using the service
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BoxService } from '../BoxService';
import { Box } from '../Box';

@Component({
selector: 'app-Data',
templateUrl: './Data.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./Data.component.css']
})

export class DataComponent implements OnInit {
uitkomst:String;
box:Box;
constructor(private boxService:BoxService) { }

zoekBarcode(barcode):void{
this.uitkomst = "ik heb info over deze barcode: " + barcode;
this.showBox(barcode);
}

showBox(barcode){
this.boxService.getBox(barcode).subscribe(data => this.box = data);

console.log(this.box.boxNumber.toString());
}
ngOnInit() {

}
}

// Box Class
import { Contentline } from "./Contentline";

export class Box {
boxNumber: number;
status: number;
shipTo: string;
shipToName: string;
contentLines: Contentline[];
}

//Contentline class
export class Contentline {
articleIdCustomer: string;
description: string;
orderId: string;
orderLineId: string;
quantity: number;
uom: string;
closet: any;
shelf: any;
deliveryDate: string;
}
```

My JSON string looks like this:

```
{
    "boxNumber": 13100973,
    "contentLines": [
        {
            "articleIdCustomer": "112050",
            "description": " Nutraclear naaldvrije connector",
            "departmentName": null,
            "deliveryDate": "2018-06-26T22:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "articleIdCustomer": "101512",
            "description": " LIJN INFUUSVERLENG 400CM 1,5 MM PE/PVC",
            "departmentName": null,
            "deliveryDate": "2018-06-27T22:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "articleIdCustomer": "101053",
            "description": " LIJN INFUUS 700CM 1X2,1MM     25ST",
            "departmentName": null,
            "deliveryDate": "2018-06-27T22:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "articleIdCustomer": "101053",
            "description": " LIJN INFUUS 700CM 1X2,1MM     25ST",
            "departmentName": null,
            "deliveryDate": "2018-07-03T22:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "articleIdCustomer": "101053",
            "description": " LIJN INFUUS 700CM 1X2,1MM     25ST",
            "departmentName": null,
            "deliveryDate": "2018-07-04T22:00:00Z"
        },
        {
            "articleIdCustomer": "101386",
            "description": " DOP AFSLUIT ENTERALE SPUIT ENFIT (PER 8",
            "departmentName": null,
            "deliveryDate": "2018-06-25T22:00:00Z"
        }
    ],
    "status": 3,
    "otherDepartments": []
}
```

Comment: This question is being asked twice a day. You need to learn what asynchronism is. Analogy: you're trying to eat a toast immediately after you put it inside the toaster. The toast is not ready at that time. It's only ready when the toaster notifies you that the toast is grilled, i.e. when the callback passed to subscribe() is called. That's what asynchronism is.

Comment: How can i be sure when my toast is ready? :P i know what asynchronism is. i already made stuff with javascript. i,m just having some difficulties with angular.

Comment: You can be sure it's ready because the callback passed to subscribe() is called. So print your box inside this callback. Not immediately after you've sent the request.

Comment: ok, thanks for helping. i now have this: this.boxService.getBox(barcode).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      data = this.box;
      console.log(this.box.boxNumber);
    }); Still saying boxNumber is undefined

Comment: `data = this.box` initializes data with this.box. You must do the reverse: `this.box = data;`.

Comment: It worked! thanks forh helping. I kinda feel stupid for making such a mistake, oeps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in typesafe object creation consider following Box class constructor (I simplified it to single field):

```
interface iBox { /* You will get this structure from HTTP get */
  articleIdCustomer: string,

}

class Box implements iBox {
  articleIdCustomer: string,
  constructor(iBox: IBox) {
    this.articleIdCustomer = 
    (typeof(iBox.articleIdCustomer) !== 'undefined') ? iBox.articleIdCustomer : undefuned
  }
}
```

and then at recieving JSON object from web:

```
this.boxService.getBox(barcode).subscribe((data: iBox) => this.box = new Box(data));
```

If some of fiels are mandatory, you can throw Errors in constructor

Answer (score -1):

Rewrite you below the line of code

```
this.boxService.getBox(barcode).subscribe(data => this.box = data);
```

as

```
this.boxService.getBox(barcode).subscribe(data:Box => this.box = data);
```

you can give type to data it automatically cast all your object accordingly.

Comment: That wouldn't compile, and specifying the type is useless, since TypeScript already knows it's a Box.

Comment: i tried your solution, i now get a red line under data: the error is: cannot find name data

Comment: Put (data:Box) like it or you can use pipe to map your data as BOX object